# javascript code works at first using setTimeout but then crashes or doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, api, settimeout

My code works for the first few minutes and then my pages crashes or it doesn't work after - it also sometimes says where my content should be "undefined", what's wrong with my code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    test();
});

function test(){
    $.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/http://xzenweb.co.uk?callback=?", 
         function(data) {
         var name = data["shares"];
            var dataString = 'shares='+name;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                success: function(html)
                {
                $("#content").html(html);
                }
            });
            return false;  
         }); 
    setTimeout("test()",5000);
 }
```

php code:

```
if(isset($_POST["shares"])) {
    echo $_POST["shares"];
}
```

Comment: It is recommended to use [the other setTimeout() syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout): setTimeout(test, 5000).

Comment: are you trying to get some 'live data' to keep to date? I would use the jQuery complete callback and move the setTimeout there... this way you don't start the timer until the last response was received (good or bad). also `clearTimeout(timeout); timeout = setTimeout(..);` and remember to declair timeout.

Comment: hi rlemon - yeah exactly that I'm trying to keep live data up to date on my page so that when someone shares the page the number goes up +1 straight away. Sorry I'm a noob, how would I go about putting that in my code?

Comment: @rlemon you should have posted that as an answer because it is most likely the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - notice I only call the timeout after successful run:

Also note that you may run into a limitation on number of calls you are allowed to do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  test();
});

function test(){
  $.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/http://xzenweb.co.uk?callback=?", 
     function(data) {
       var name = data["shares"];
       var dataString = 'shares='+name;
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "index.php",
         data: dataString,
         cache: false,
         success: function(html) {
           $("#content").html(html);
           setTimeout(test,5000);
         }
      });
   }); 
 }
```

---

Here is a test of just the json loop until the number changed or 10 calls (since the user may already have shared)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var savedData ="";
  var cnt = 10;
  $(document).ready(function(){
  test();
});

function test(){
  $.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/http://xzenweb.co.uk?callback=?", 
     function(data) {
       var shares = data["shares"];
// change this line to 
// $("#content").html(shares);
// when you are happy
       $("#content").html(cnt + ":"+shares+" - "+new Date());
       if (cnt > 0) {
         if (savedData == "" || savedData == shares ) {
           setTimeout(test,1000);
         }
       }
       savedData = shares;
       cnt--
  });
}

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi @mplungjan I tried this code but it still crashes after a while and says something went wrong! :)

Comment: oh how many calls are you allowed to do - and how can you get around this, because I always want live data

Comment: the response below seems to work fine though, wonder what's up?

Comment: this: if(isset($_POST["shares"])) {
    echo $_POST["shares"];
}

Comment: he ignores errors and run again even when he gets some. How long does my code run before the SNAP?

Comment: with his code I could share my page and the number on xzenweb.co.uk would go up by 1 straight away...with your code is a bit more delayed? It's usually around 5-10 mins before the snap

Comment: I'm busy creating an app but for the first part I'm trying to display the share count on the page - so if somebody shares the page the count will go up +1 without having to refresh

Comment: why do you think it's crashing? :(

Comment: because if it didn't repeat the call you would have to refresh the page to see the amount of shares wouldn't you, where I'd like the user to share the page and see the amount of shares go up +1 without refreshing

Comment: lol how do I do that? Sorry I am the noob of noobs at this sort of thing - just learning

Comment: I've changed the line like you said and it doesn't seem to be updating - you have to refresh to update

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe it's a good idea to use .done, .fail and .always. And to do the setTimeout in .always (no matter if the request was a success - done, or an error - fail.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  test();
});

function test(){
  $.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/http://xzenweb.co.uk?callback=?", 
     function(data) {
       var name = data["shares"];
       var dataString = 'shares='+name;
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "index.php",
         data: dataString,
         cache: false
      })
      .done(function(html) { $("#content").html(html); })
      .always(function() { setTimeout(test,5000); })
   }); 
 }
```

Or inside the ajax you could use the complete to set the timeout (to be sure it is called even on error), like this:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "index.php",
         data: dataString,
         cache: false,
         success: function(html) {
           $("#content").html(html);
         },
         complete: function() {
           setTimeout(test,5000);
         }
      });
```

Comment: Hi @angel I tried the first one but my page does not update after a while! :(

Comment: Do a few console.log one just after function test() {, another after function(data) { and another in the complete/always function, so you can get the idea where it breaks. And let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I suggested from the comments above.

```
var timeout; // create a variable named `timeout` assign nothing to it.

$(document).ready(function(){ // I really don't see the point in $(document).ready, if you include your code in the body of the document this should not be needed.
    test();
});

function test(){
    $.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/http://xzenweb.co.uk?callback=?", 
         function(data) {
         var name = data["shares"];
            var dataString = 'shares='+name;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#content").html(html);
                },
                complete: function(xhr, status) { // I run after success and error callbacks have fired.
                   clearTimeout(timeout); // I clear any timeouts assigned to timeout variable. (these are denoted with an integer ID)
                   timeout = setTimeout(test , 5000); // knowing there is no longer a timeout waiting to fire, I can re-assign a timeout to the variable.
                }
            });
            return false;  
         }); 
}
```

I have commented the code a bit more to help clerify what is happening.

More can be read about jQuery.ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
Also you should read up on the mechanics of setTimeout [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Comment: then you can modify the code to do anything you want. in the complete callback you get 'status' - you can check there or move the setTimeout to the success, just ensure you handle the error case so the user knows and is not just sitting on a stagnant page.

Comment: this code seems to be working the best for me! :) Could you tell me how it works? I'm a bit of a noob and I'd like to learn.

Comment: oh no haha just when I was thinking this code was working - the google chrome crash page came up :(

Comment: @AndrewCharlton if you are not getting any errors could the chrome crash be caused by some other reason? does facebook limit you to N requests per minute/hour?

Comment: I don't think they do and if they do it's much more than I'm requesting - what could the error be?

Comment: can you try this in a browser outside of Chrome and see if you get a better error rather than the "i'm dead jim" google crash page. Check your memory usage as well? This could be a leak causing the page to crash. all I can think of.

Comment: Yeah I will do, I don't know why it's crashing either :S

Comment: hmm it's not crashing in ie - just chrome :S

Comment: yeah it's quite high but nothing too bad... it's now coming up undefined in ie! There must be an error somewhere

Comment: If you still cannot solve this get a few more rep and join the chat (Javascript room) for some more help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12392/discussion-between-rlemon-and-andrew-charlton)